# Interpretation Output lme (Intr)

Tags: lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I`m getting this output from R for my mixed model with lme package. The output seems to be making sense so far and I can interpret it. However I am wondering how I should interpret the correlation (Intr) for fixed effects? It seems to be pretty high (-.989).

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: df 
       AIC    BIC    logLik
  199.4223 216.44 -93.71115

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 + IV1 | group
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev    Corr  
(Intercept) 1.0672154 (Intr)
IV1         0.2603861 -0.997
Residual    0.4560879       

Fixed effects: DV ~ 1 + IV1
                Value Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 2.0682144 0.3329804 99 6.211221       0
IV1         0.4129596 0.0867471 99 4.760500       0
 Correlation:
```

> ```
>         (Intr)
> IV1       -0.989
> ```

```
Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-2.4434151 -0.5169251  0.0502596  0.5886701  2.0888820 

Number of Observations: 128
Number of Groups: 28
```